# The warning: STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT. Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, machine-learning-model

I am stuck with my Data Science project. When I perform my code:

```
log_clf = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000, C=2)
svm_clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(C=0.01,loss = "hinge", random_state = 42))
voting_clf = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('lr', log_clf), ('rf', rnd_clf), ('svc', svm_clf)],voting='hard')
voting_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get the warning:

> Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text
> editor
>
> C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model_logistic.py:763:
> ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1): STOP: TOTAL
> NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.
>
> Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as
> shown in:
> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
> n_iter_i = _check_optimize_result(
> C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm_base.py:985:
> ConvergenceWarning: Liblinear failed to converge, increase the number
> of iterations.   warnings.warn("Liblinear failed to converge, increase
> " C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm_base.py:985:
> ConvergenceWarning: Liblinear failed to converge, increase the number
> of iterations.

I have increased the max_iter for LogisticRegression, this doesn't help.
I saw some recommendations to ignore such warnings, is it a good strategy or I can handle the issue?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Any luck on this?